# Restricting file size in snowflake multipart unload to a specific value

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to unload some data from Snowflake to AWS S3 using COPY option. I want each individual file to be less than 1MB. I tried using MAX_FILE_SIZE attribute, but still some of my files are greater than 1MB. Is there a way I can force Snowflake to stick to the size limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not guaranteed, especially for very small file sizes (default is 16MB) and it is documented on our docs via this note:

```
Note

The COPY command unloads one set of table rows at a time. If you set a very small MAX_FILE_SIZE value, the amount of data in a set of rows could exceed the specified size.
```

In general, the actual file size and number of files unloaded are determined by the total amount of data and number of nodes available for parallel processing.

You can read more about this [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location).